# Asynchronous form-data POST request with xmlhhtprequest

Tags: ajax, node.js, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file to the REST Api of Octoprint, which should be done by sending a POST request with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`
(http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/fileops.html#upload-file)

I am using NodeJS and two libraries, XmlHttpRequest and form-data. When trying:

```
    var xhr = new xmlhttprequest() ;
    var form = new formData() ;
    form.append('exampleKey', 'exampleValue');
    xhr.open("POST","octopi.local/api/local", true) ;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data") ;
    xhr.send(form) ;
```

I get an error at the xhr.send line :

```
    TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
```

If I make a synchronous request by using xhr.open("POST",url,false), this error disappears.

Why is it so ? Is there a way to turn it into an asynchronous request ?

**EDIT** Actually, I don't really understand the documentation. I suppose that I should set the file I want to upload by using `form.append("filename", filepath, "exampleName")`, but I am not sure about that. The fact is that I noticed that I get the TypeError even if I try a simplified request, without sending any file.

**EDIT2** This is the modified code, which returns the same error :

```
    var XMLHttpRequest=require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest ;
    var FormData = require('form-data');

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("key","value" );

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', "octopi.local/api/files/");
    xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Where are you setting the file you want to upload?

Comment: I think `asynchronous / synchronous` is the key here. When you set the POST to synchronous, all the code after the callback function is executed AFTER the callback has returned.On the contrary, in asynchronous mode, the code after the callback is executed before it returns. Therefore if you need its result, it won't be available  hence the error message. : so I don't think there is a way unless you call another callback within the callback to perform the desired actions

Comment: @VasilDininski : Actually, I don't really understand the documentation. I suppose that I should set the file I want to upload by using form.append("filename", filepath, "exampleName"), but I am not sure about that. The fact is that I noticed that I get the TypeError even if I try a simplified request, without sending any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time working on this, I finally managed to upload a file. If you use NodeJS, don't rely on the MDN documentation: it tells what the libraries should do, not what they can actually do on the node platform. You should only focus on the docs available on GitHub.

It seems that it is not currently possible to send a form with XMLHttpRequest : I tried using JSON.stringify(form) but then wireshark tells me that the request is not a multipart/formdata request.

If you want to upload a file, you should rather use the 'request' module. The following has worked for me :

```
exports.unwrappeduploadToOctoprint = function(){
  "use strict" ;
  var form ={
    file: {
           value: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/test2.gcode'),
           options: { filename: 'test2.gcode'}
         }
  };

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://192.168.1.24/api/files/local',
    headers: { 'x-api-key': 'E0A2518FB11B40F595FC0068192A1AB3'},
    formData: form
  };

  var req = request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(body);
  });
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. i was trying to execute REST API of DashDB where i was passing a CSV file. However i am a little worried about fs.readFileSync. What happens when the file size is about 500MB or in GB?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have some typos in your code. Use code snippet below instead. Replace the relevant parts according to your needs

```
var fileToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
var data = new FormData();
data.append("myfile", fileToUpload);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "upload_endpoint");
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: It returns the same error : `TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer` . Do you have any idea of what the reason could be ?

Comment: @ClémentVgnc can you pls share the modified code snippet

Comment: @ClémentVgnc Upload endpoint is POST /api/files/(string: location). location accepts either sdcard or local. So valid endpoints are **/api/files/sdcard** & **/api/files/local** The Form Param name should be **file** & the value should be a file, NOT a string.

Comment: How do i create fileToUpload from a string path? I have a file in the filesystem and i have the path to that file.